# Spring inject values

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, inject

I am very new to spring and started using.
I have a  requirement where i have something like properties
like regions..US,UK

```
Regions
-------
US
UK
```

And when i read US it shud have values something like

```
US
----
(KEY)primary----VALUE(primaryValue)
(KEY)secondary----VALUE(secondaryValue)
```

.
.
similarly

```
UK
--
(KEY)primary----VALUE(primaryValue)
(KEY)secondary----VALUE(secondaryValue)
```

.
.
and the regions might increase as requirement changes and the key value pairs below it too

Someone hint me so i can proceed
Thank you in advance

Comment: You want to say I18N in website ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create two bean a `List` and a `Map`, in other word `List<Map>` is you  need

```
<bean id="regions" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="usMap" />
            <ref bean="ukMap" />                
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

and

```
<util:map id="usMap" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
    <entry key="primary" value="someValue"/>
    <entry key="secondary" value="someValue"/>
</util:map>
```

Comment: Thank you joshi this is what i was expecting but how do i make use of them in the application..?

Comment: Just use the bean `regions` in your application, I assume you already have spring context in your app

Comment: yes yes....i do have a spring context...Let me try and post that way...Anyways thanq very much for timely response..:-)

Comment: Can you please me tell me how should the regions Bean class look like cos when i try creating the bean regions i get the following error
(org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException) org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'circles' defined in file [D:\Projects\Bean.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'US' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'US' is defined

Comment: Region bean is ArrayList, did you create bean with name `US`

Comment: context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/config/Bean.xml");
java.util.ArrayList region=(java.util.ArrayList) ContextThread.context.getBean("regions");

This is my line of code but the application is not able to get context object when i add the above mentioned lines in Bean.xml
When i remove the lines the context object gets created and i am able to create other beans...

Comment: did you create bean with name `US` ?

Comment: If i create US and UK beans then i have to Change my code tomorrow if i get something like ASIA
But my intention is i shoud not do that .....my application should not be touched when i add new regions or new key value pairs

Is it possible..?

Comment: <bean id="Regions" class="com.ppt.exp.Regions">
  <property name="US">
  <bean class="com.nxl.exp.Mapping">
  </bean>
  </property>

  <property name="UK">
   <bean class="com.nxl.exp.Mapping">
   </bean>
  </property>
 </bean>

And the Mapping class containig a MAP...Is it possible that way..?

Comment: Theres nothing wrong...May be i was thinking the other way...Now what should the US bean and UK bean contain and If i have a new bean tomorrow ASIA..I have to create its bean too..?
COrrect me if iam wrong

Comment: Yes add another bean in xml and add it to list in xml bean definatioon

Answer (score 1):

You can make different properties in according to region , when server will start all the properties file will load.You can make PropertiesFileReader.java file which will read u'r properties.

Comment: NO no..i dont want to use property files but instead use a Bean.xml whose contextobject can be used to get the properties and use in my application